# React Native: how to combine inline elements so they get wrapped together

Tags: react-native, word-wrap, react-native-flexbox

I have a list of comma-separated inline touchables like this:

```
[(<TouchableOpacity><Text>a</Text></TouchableOpacity>),
 (<Text>, </Text>),
 (<TouchableOpacity><Text>b</Text></TouchableOpacity>),
 (<Text>, </Text>),
 (<TouchableOpacity><Text>c</Text></TouchableOpacity>)]
```

rendering as a comma-separated string of items:

```
a, b, c
```

The problem is that sometimes comma gets wrapped to a newline, which looks kinda ugly:

```
a, b, c
, d
```

How to combine two "inline" elements so they get wrapped together?

**Update.** Code:

```
...

    let items1 = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        const text = makeid(i % 10 + 1);

        items1.push((<TouchableOpacity><Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{text}</Text></TouchableOpacity>));
        items1.push((<Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>, </Text>));
    }

    return (<View style={styles.li}>
        {items1}
    </View>);

...

// just generates some random string
function makeid(len) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    li: {
        width: "100%",
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        marginBottom: 5,
        paddingLeft: 10
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the styles and the code for rendering this array?

Comment: Note that Text accept an onPress prop, so if you're adding TouchableOpacity just to get onPress support, then it's quite useless. In that case you can simply remove them and wrap all Text blocks in a parent Text (since Text supports nesting) and I think your problem is solved.

Comment: @Milore It works. Surely will use it as a workaround for now, but sadly it also leaves a user without nice animation provided by <TouchableOpacity>. I also think your comment deserves to be an answer. It would be nice if you put a short note on how text wrapping works in React Native.

Comment: @PritishVaidya Sure. Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Starting solution**

According to the official documentation:

> `Text` supports nesting, styling, and touch handling.

So if you're adding `TouchableOpacity` just to get `onPress` support, then it's quite useless.
In that case you can simply remove it and wrap all `Text` blocks in a parent `Text` and your problem is solved.

As you correctly note, this

> leaves a user without nice animation provided by `<TouchableOpacity>`.

I thought to a better solution and it was not so far :)

**2. Other (and better?) solution**

Simply wrap your `<TouchableOpacity>` and related `<Text>` with comma in a single `<View>` with `flexDirection: 'row'` and add it to the array you're going to render.

```
  render() {
    let items1 = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      const text = makeid((i % 10) + 1);

      items1.push(
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>, </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.li}>{items1}</View>
    );
  }
```

This way you're sure comma do not separate from its previous word and you benefit of `<TouchableOpacity>` animation.

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/forlorn-macaroni-and-cheese) you can find a working example.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hooray, it works! So much thanks for helping to figure it out.